# Making a link using ln -s

Tags: ln

I'm trying to make a link using:

```
ln -s /Backup files/ /link 1
```

Instead of making the link, I'm get the following output:

> ln: target '/link' is not a directory

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to quote spaces (or possibly avoid them altogether): `ln -s '/Backup files/' '/link 1'. Spaces in pathnames cause pain when used on the command line.

Comment: I'm not sure it's a duplicate of the other questions. But to tell you what you are doing wrong, we need to understand what you want to do and it's not clear. What is `/Backup files/`? One file? Several files? What is `/link 1`?

Answer (score 7):

A shell will typically break a

```
ln -s /Backup files/ /link 1
```

command line into these words:

- `ln`
- `-s`
- `/Backup`
- `files/`
- `/link`
- `1`

From the first word, it will derive the command to execute (something like `/bin/ln` found by searching all the directories listed in the `$PATH` variable for a file called `ln`) and will pass all those words as separate arguments to that `/bin/ln` executable.

`ln` will understand the second argument (`-s`) as an option that means create symbolic links instead of hard links, and then the rest as a number of non-option arguments. When `ln` receives more than two non-option arguments, it understands the last one as being a directory where to create symlinks to the other arguments.

So, that's asking `ln` to create 3 symlinks:

- `1/Backup` -> `/Backup`
- `1/files` -> `files/`
- `1/link` -> `/link`

If the `1` directory doesn't exist or if it's a file that is not of type *directory*, it will complain.

If you wanted `ln` to create a symlink called `/link 1` that points to `/Backup files/`¹, you'd need to pass those arguments to `ln`:

- `ln`
- `-s`
- `/Backup files/`
- `/link 1`

In most shells, that can be done with:

```
ln -s '/Backup files/' '/link 1'
```

The `'` characters, like the space characters, are part of the shell syntax. Here, they're used to tell that whatever is inside the `'...'` is to be treated literally. Specifically, the *space* character loses its signification as an argument delimiter and is instead included literally in the argument passed to `ln`. Some shell implementations support more *quoting* operators like `"..."`, `$'...'`, `$"..."` or backslash. In Korn-like shells like `bash`, all these are equivalent:

```
ln -s "/Backup files/" "/link 1"
ln -s $'Backup files/' $'/link 1'
ln -s Backup\ files/ /link\ 1
```

And you can of course combine them like:

```
'ln' "-"'s' "Back"up\ files/ ''""/link' '$'1'
```

---

<sup>¹ Note though that if `link 1` existed and was of type directory (or symlink eventually resolving to a directory), `ln -s 'Backup files/' '/link 1'` would actually create a `Backup files` symlink in that directory instead (a `/link 1/Backup files` -> `/Backup files/` symlink). With GNU `ln`, you can avoid that by using the `-T` option.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You are missing double quotes on your filenames.  Since they contain spaces, they need to be quoted:

```
$ ln -s "/Backup files" "/link 1"
```

Comment: Not all shells support double-quotes as quoting operators. `rc`, `es` or `akanga` don't for instance (where `"` is not a special character). Single quotes would be more portable here (and also quote more characters).